# Why i cant get value from xml node

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this string XML:

```
  "<Selection xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">184028.884942584,664923.573252621,183875.392224311,664759.166484197</Selection>
  <PipeCount xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">78</PipeCount>
  <ControlValveCount xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">4</ControlValveCount>
  <ServiceValveCount xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">26</ServiceValveCount>"
```

I need to get from XML above values(for example value of Selection node).

Here how I do it:

```
        var parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data.documentElement.innerHTML, "text/xml");
        var val = parser.getElementsByTagName("Selection").nodeValue;
```

But val is null.
Any idea what I do wrong why val is null?

UPDATE:
I tryed this:
    var val = parser.getElementsByTagName("Selection")[0].nodeValue;
The val is null.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, not a single element. The collection has no `nodeValue`

Comment: Try `[0].nodeValue`.